# array index out of bounds when deleting from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when i try to remove a node from a child in firebase, it crashes my code giving a fatal error saying "index out of bounds". The end result is to delete the data associated with the ID from the UID. i have attached the code for the cell removing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        var listOfUID = [String]()
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(currentEmail!)

        ref.observe(.childAdded , with: { snapshot in
            if !snapshot.exists() {return}

            print(snapshot.key)

            let listOfUID = [snapshot.key]
            let name = listOfUID[indexPath.row]

            ref.queryOrdered(byChild: name ).queryEqual(toValue: name).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                snapshot.ref.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, reference) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("There has been an error:\(error)")

                    }
                  data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                  tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
                })
            })
        })


    }
 }
```

some reason things like `let name = listOfUID[indexPath.row - 1]`won't fix it either.

I also think its good to mention that the current email has a scanner that takes out the "."

I have uploaded how the structure of database is setup

```
{
  "email@yahoocom" : {
    "-LtUztWPbQias7bh5C2L" : {
      "message" : "Didn’t",
      "teamName" : "jah"
    },
    "-LtUzumEkb2kjK4qeU6E" : {
      "message" : "D d",
      "teamName" : "did if"
    },
    "-LtVCbxDu6DqxWv7LHzp" : {
      "message" : "Cc’d",
      "teamName" : "xdfff"
    }
  },
  "nice@nicecom" : {
    "-LtSjXIKnKXKgp-XCzdP" : {
      "message" : "Test 2",
      "teamName" : "test 1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please only tag with `xcode` if your question is about the XCode IDE. For general questions about iOS programming, tag with `ios`.

Comment: Gottcha, sorry :)

Comment: There are a number of issues with that code that will cause it to crash, not to mention adding observers to the nodes you want to delete (?). I would suggest rethinking your strategy of how data is stored in your tableView datasource. If you read a set of Firebase nodes and keep them in an array, you will also have the node keys at that time as well so store them in the datasource as well. From there, when deleting a row, you will know what node key it is and can directly delete that node. That avoids having to query for the node and then deleting the found node.

Comment: im a little confused because I've been using the firebase api for this whole entire project... not going to lie I can't believe creating a delete function is this much frustrating and this much time lul

Comment: It's frustrating because of how it's being done. It's actually a straightforward process but it's being over complicated in that code; you don't need .childAdded or even a query to make this work. Generally speaking, you shouldn't have to query for  node with a known key to then turn around and delete it. When the nodes are loaded into your dataSource to start with, you keep track of what nodes they are from snapshot.key. When you swipe to delete, read get the row index from the swipe, look up that object in your dataSource array, get the node key. Then remove it from Firebase.

Comment: Even after I simply it, it’ll delete the whole entire child, not just the the UID created within the child

Comment: If you would include a snippet of your Firebase structure (as text) as well as the code your using to read it in, we may be able to come up with a solution to help.

Comment: I updated the question with a picture of the structure  and the thought process behind it... I'm not sure how you wanted me to include it in text.

Comment: also I want to point out I really appreciate your help, you have no idea how much I appreciate It

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Comment: uploaded the JSON for the scruture, thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to improve the code. I had to make a bunch of assumptions here as there was some vagueness in the question. Two suggestions:

1) Don't use email addresses as node keys. You have to manipulate them as you mention and what if the users email changes? You would have to go through and read and then write back out every place it's used. Create a key with .childByAutoId and then store the senders uid as a child. The uid  always refers back to that user. Using .childByAutoId disassociates the key from the data which provides a lot more flexibility.

2) You don't need to query for a node to delete it. If you know the key, you can use that to delete

Here's what your users and teams node should look like:

```
users
   uid_0 //a users uid
      user_name: "Henry"
      email: "henry@thing.com"
      team: "team_0"

   uid_1 //another users uid
      user_name: "Leroy"
      email: "leroy@jenkins.com"
      team: "team_1"

teams
   team_0 //created with .childByAutoId
      team_name: "Cool Team"
   team_1
      team_name: "Awesome Team"
```

If Team A becomes Cool Team, you can change it in one place instead of for every user. Also, you can change a users email without affecting any other code or nodes in your app.

There's not a lot of info in the question but it looks like other users messages to a user are stored within universalscout node

```
universalscout
   uid_0 //the uid of the user that's receiving the message
      message_id_0 //created with childByAutoId
         from_uid: "uid_1" //the uid of the user that sent the message
         msg: "Didn't"
      message_id_1
         from_uid: "uid_2"
         msg: "D d"
      message_id_2
         from_uid: "uid_3"
         msg: "Cc'd"
```

So then a class to hold the message data and store in the dataSource which backs your tableView

```
class MessageClass {
   var msg_id = ""
   var from_uid = ""
   var msg = ""
)
```

and then a class dataSource array to store them in

```
var myMessageArray = [MessageClass]()
```

So when reading, iterate over the messages in uid_0, read each one, create a MessageClass storing the msg_id, who it's from and the message. Add each class to the dataSource array. It appears you know how to read the data from Firebase and populate the dataSource so I will skip that code.

Then finally when deleting.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        let messageToDelete = myMessageArray[indexPath.row]
        let firebaseKey = messageToDelete.msg_id
        let ref = your_firebase.child("universalscout").child(this users uid).child(firebaseKey)
        ref.remove()
        //remove the row from the dataSource
        //reload the tableView
    }
 }
```

One thing that was not mentioned in the question is if there is an observer watching for removed nodes. If not, then the above code is good to go. If so, you'll need to alter where the row is removed from the dataSource and when to reload the tableView.

Comment: I’ll get on to restructuring, I greatly appreciate it!